# What are the advantages of using Keycloak?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, keycloak

What are the advantages of using a 3rd Party service like Keycloak for User Management instead of building it all from Scratch within the own database?

Comment: Does this help https://medium.com/keycloak/keycloak-essentials-86254b2f1872

Comment: Not too much. I can see that it a time advantage implementing it with Keycloak, but I wonder how much more time it would really cost to set it up myself and what do I need to pay attention to which Keycloak delivers out of the box.

Comment: There are a lot of security standard related to Authentication and Authorization that probably if you implement by yourself chances are you may get it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious one is that it is much faster to set up keycloak than to build it all yourself. This is especially true for bigger applications with complex user modells. It also make it easier to adapt new authentication mechanisms in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The first advantage is that it is opensource
It gives you out of the box solution for Identity management.
You can configure it and forget it.
It gives you security solutions like MFA as well including TOTP and HOTP
The user management is good as well, you can create roles and map it to users and give permissions based on roles.
You can directly rely on keycloak and redirect user (from ui) for login purpose or you can use your own api and call keycloak for authentication.

I can go on but you get the idea :)

Comment: Can Keycloak perfom slower than if I selfimplement it in my database?

Comment: What do you mean by slower than, its not clear to me. If you can give an idea of what kind of application you are trying to manage access to that would help too.

Comment: It is a simple web application which will access the WebServices and I want to manage the access through Keycloak.

Comment: If you want to manage user access to web app, you will have to set up user data inside keycloak. It is easy and quite flexible.